# Undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'

Tags: c++, linker, libcurl

first I woud like to say that I saw similar post , and I posted this one on it but was removed... so all is in the title. I understood that it could be a problem at the linker step but I don't know why. Indeed, I linked all the (*.a) files on my Code::Blocks projet and added the different paths of the curl library in Linker options and search directories.

I also tried to manually compil and link but I did not succeed.

```
g++ -L ..\lib\curl\lib64 -I ..\lib\curl\include -lcurl main.cpp
```

Another attempt

```
g++ main.cpp -L ..\lib\curl\lib64 -I ..\lib\curl\include -lcurl -o test.exe
```

This is the error : " undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init' "

This is my code , maybe the source of troubles is here but I don't think so (tried the static lib too )

```
#include <iostream>
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>


using namespace std;

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;}

int main(void)
{

    /*ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();*/

    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "page.html";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Order matters when linking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24675715/1413395), put `main.cpp` first.

Comment: It is the same...

Guys I really don't know why I can't get it work, I need an external eye cause I'm pretty sure to do all right xD

Comment: Could you edit your post with the linker command line you had tried please?

Comment: g++ main.cpp -L ..\lib\curl\lib64 -I ..\lib\curl\include -lcurl -o test.exe as you told me :)